# Elements exceeds width of parent div, because of nowrap white-space setting

Tags: html, css, overflow, whitespace

```
<div class="external_wall_right_col_sub_ad">
<div class="external_wall_right_col_sub_ad_img">
<h4>
<a href="http://localhost/PublishWall/oglasnik/oglas/ogled/2312/Razgorsek-Sedezne-garniture-Bari">Razgoršek, Sedežne garniture, Bari</a>
</h4>
<p></p>
</div>
```

I have this html structure. The width of main wrapper is set to 165 px. When I change white-space to nowrap in the h4 a, it seems like the width of the wrap doesnt apply anymore,check the picture below(The title outlined with red should stop at the black line).

[image]

I have overflow set to hidden. How can I make the text stop when it exceeds the width

Comment: Remove the no-wrap rule :-)

Comment: Post the CSS would be great to, and this is what the no wrapper does.

Comment: Please post the CSS also or put it in a fiddle so that we have a working example to look at. From the looks of things @BillyMoat is correct and you need to remove the no-wrap rule (on both the <h4> tag and the <p> tag.

Comment: I know the no wrap causes the problem, but I want to use no wrap and avoid this problem.